# Extraer datos del localstorage para calcular valores mayores y menores

Tags: jquery

Como puedo calcular con nota mayor y menor tomando como ejemplo, la resolución que pusieron de promedio en Extraer datos del localstorage para realizar calculos
Desde ya gracias

Comment: Hola, pon ejemplos por favor, y no estaría mal que nos indiques que has intentado.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so], te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Tu pregunta no está clara, deberías agregar lo que has intentado. Puedes leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Hola, puedes dar más información de lo que necesitas hacer y sobre cual es tu problema?